# Javascript - Object State

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I may be approaching this incorrectly...

I'm trying to keep track of an objects state internally and use it to call modified methods:

```
createObject = function() {
  this.a = 1

  this.method1 = function() {
  if (this.a == 1 ) {
    //do stuff
    this.a = 0
  }
}

var x = new createObject()
```

Unfortunately, state isn't being internally tracked.  If I change the properties of another object it works perfectly however:

```
otherObj = { a:1 }

createObject = function() {

  this.method1 = function() {
  if (this.a == 1 ) {
    //do stuff
    otherObject.a = 0
  }

}

var x = new createObject()
```

Is this the correct way to approach this?

Comment: "Unfortunately, state isn't being internally tracked." What is going wrong exactly ?

Comment: @Sniffer - My method isn't running correctly as a result of _this.a_ not being updated

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have problem, because `this` in `method1()` is different from `this` in outer function. That's because in JS functions create scope.

**First approach**

So you might want `a` to be a variable, not a property of `this`:

```
createObject = function() {
  // 'a' is now available here...
  var a = 1

  this.method1 = function() {
    // ... and here as well.
    if (a == 1 ) {
      a = 0
    }
  }
}
```

**Second approach**

Alternatively, you might want to hold a reference to the outer `this` in a helper variable (called `self` in this example):

```
createObject = function() {
  // 'self' is a regular varialbe, referencing 'this'
  var self = this;
  this.a = 1

  this.method1 = function() {
    // Here, self !== this, because 'this' in method1() 
    // is different from 'this' in outer function.
    // So we can access 'self.a':
    if (self.a == 1 ) {
      //do stuff
      self.a = 0
    }
  }
}
```

**Third approach**

Finally, you can also use `bind()` to tie outer `this` to your `method1()`:

```
var createObject = function () {
    this.a = 1

    this.method1 = function () {
        console.log(this.a);
        if (this.a == 1) {
            this.a = 0
        }
    }.bind(this);
    // ^ note `bind(this)` above. Now, 'this' inside 'method1'
    // is same as 'this' in outer function.
}
```

[Here is a doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) for `bind()`. Note that it's not available in IE < 9.

Comment: well explained answer

Comment: When you call `method1` as a method of `createObject`, doesn't `this.a` inside `method1` refer to the same `a` referenced by `this` inside the `createObject` constructor ?

Comment: @Sniffer - if you call it this way, yes, it should. I skipped that part, because OP didn't specify how he calls `method1()` - looking at symptoms I assumed he has a `this`-issue.

Comment: This is a very good answer thanks, but it seems strange that there is no implicit way for an object to change one of its own properties.  You addressed this in point 2, but to pass that out I need to create a reference to itself inside itself? (maybe I'm missing something here)

Comment: @Sniffer - exactly thats what I would have thought which is why I raised this question :)

Comment: @JamieStrauss - yes, it's common practice to have `var that = this;` (and it's called in a various ways, common are: `that`, `self`, `_this`). If you want to __really__ understand them, I cannot recommend anything more higly that [Dimtry Soshnikov's blog series](http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/ecmascript/) - it's a long read, but does an exceptional job at explaining scopes and other JS features. Certainly better that reading ECMAScript standard itself ;)

Comment: Thanks @kamituel I've got my weekend homework now :)

Comment: I come back to this ~2.5  years later (after an upvote), and this still stands as one of those answers that gave me an "aha!" moment.

Comment: @JamieStrauss glad to hear that! Also note that after those few years, we now almost have EcmaScript 6 (almost, because to run ES6 in most browsers you need to transpile it using tools like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)), which means that for some of the use cases you can use classes now, [like in this example](https://jsfiddle.net/xdLhw8nh/).

Answer (score 0):

This result can by achieved this days by using something like this:

```
const obj = {};

obj.state = {
  isLoaded: false,
  isOpen: false,
};

obj.setState = (newState) => {
  // Before using obj.setState => result Object { isLoaded: false, isOpen: false }
  console.log(obj.state); 
  obj.state = { ...obj.state, ...newState };
  // After using obj.setState ex. obj.setState({new:''}) => result Object { isLoaded: false, isOpen: false, new: "" }
  console.log(obj.state); 
};
```

That approach is more or less how it would work in ReactJS, you have source object in this example **obj.state** and setter **obj.setState**

What the **obj.setState** does is it gets values from current **obj.state** and new obj then combines them into new updated obj saved instead of current **obj.state**

You don't have to put both in one object like I did but seems like a good way to organize things